# Isotope issue - When resizing browser images overlap

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, image, jquery-isotope

I´m trying to get Isotope working correctly on my website, except some images overlap when resizing the screen.

When searching I found the following `$(window).load(function(){ ..... });`.
Except I have no idea how to make it work on the following page:
http://maxvanderpluijm.nl/bbtest2/zorgappartementen/

Could somebody help me please, I'm kinda lost over here :(

Thanks in advance!!!

Greets,
Max

Comment: Could you post the relevant code from your page into your question?

Comment: Hi @cfnerd, check out: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/mazzomaxy/7cwdzu6t/2/#&togetherjs=EKjFzoBa9i)

This is a portion of the complete code. So I don't know if this is enough.. Sorry, like I said, I'm kinda lost.. 

Thanks for your help!!!